# Email aliasing with qmail

Tags: email, plesk, qmail

I'm trying to set up email domain aliasing in qmail (I'm on a Plesk server). What should happen is that emails sent to *user*@myalias.com get sent to *user*@realdomain.com (regardless of what *user* is). I would like this to happen without having to set up redirects and mess around with that sort of thing.

I've followed the details on [this forum post](http://forums.theplanet.com/lofiversion/index.php/t55333.html) with limited success. I only made changes to the qmail config as all other config is already there and correct as the myalias.com domain is set up through Plesk ...

1. modify /var/qmail/control/virtualdomains
2. add myalias.com:60 ("60" corresponds to the integer of the realdomain.com that is in the same file)
3. restart qmail service

Logs are showing that qmail accepts the incoming email to @myalias.com and then routes it to @realdomain.com. The email then goes missing and is never actually delivered.

Any thoughts on where/how I could dig deeper to figure out what's happening to the email?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just following up on this older question of mine. It is all working well now. I had the NOC check the server and they corrected it for me. Had something to do with remotehosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Does the logfile of realdomain.com show that it is even accepting or seeing the incoming redirects?

Try redirecting the email to another domain. If they end up at the other domain, then the problem lies with the domain you're trying to really send it to.

If they don't appear there at all, then it goes back to how they're being redirected and you can focus on that part.